# Debug Boost.Serialization Address Tracking

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

Roughly speaking, I have an object `o` and a pointer to that object `po = &o`, which I serialize like this:

```
// Somewhere
ar & o;

// Somewhere else, but after somewhere
ar & po;
```

When serializing `po`, Boost.Serialization should discover that it has already serialized `o` and not serialize `*po` again. I have a situation where the library fails at discovering this situation and instead serializes `o` twice.

Unfortunately, all attempts at reproducing this behaviour in a simple example failed, and the original code is way too large to be posted here. So instead of a solution to the problem, I ask for a pointer to the relevant code section in Boost.Serialization which tracks the addresses and determines whether a pointer needs to be "deeply" serialized or not. I hope I can then do the debugging myself.

Of course, any best guesses about what the error might be are also welcome, but I don't want to strain your crystal balls too much. ;-)

Btw, I use `boost::archive::text_oarchive` if that is relevant.

Comment: +1 for the crystal balls line :) No, `text_oarchive` is not very relevant, although I find that `xml_oarchive` is nice to get some udnerstanding of the tracking references.

Comment: does `BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(Object, boost::serialization::track_always)` help (if only to highlight conflicting traits)?

Comment: Nope it didn't. But thanks a lot for your efforts, anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code section in question is the `save_pointer()` function in [basic_oarchive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/src/basic_oarchive.cpp).

Boost.Serialization uses two characteristics to check whether an object has already been serialized: The object address and the object type. The address part is obvious, and if you think about also the type part makes sense. My problem was that I did *not* think about it and only checked that the two addresses in question are the same. This indeed held true, but since the types were different, the serialization library assumed it were two different objects.

Comment: Hehehe. I nearly gave you that answer with _"Similar things apply to runtime dynamic types of polymorphic classes."_ But I couldn't connect the dots (they were outside my field of vision :)). Kudos for posting the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The assumption you make is that Boost Serialization tracks instances on references. This is a false assumption.</strike>

AFAIR it tracks instances on pointers (and smart pointers).

Similar things apply to runtime dynamic types of polymorphic classes.

Comment: a) Tracking works (i.e. only one serialization) in all cases I tried, e.g. if you do `ar & o & po;` or any variant of it.
b) The `pointer conflict` exception (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/exceptions.html#pointer_conflict) only makes sense if references are tracked as well. So unless you show me an excerpt of the documentation which explicitly proves your point, I assume your answer is wrong.

Comment: Mmm. @gTcV I must agree with that reading. Then again, Object Tracking is quite tricky ([rereading this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking)) so until we have a SSCCE I'm afraid it's too crystal bally.